# Rigidity for the category of comodules over a Hopf algebra

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories, bialgebras

On this page

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rigid+monoidal+category

there is a discussion of rigidity (left-right duality) for the catagory of 
modules over a Hopf algebra. What happens if we look at 
the category of comodules over a Hopf algebra? Do we still
get a rigid category? If so, does there exist any general relationship between the left and right duals?

Comment: For modules for a Hopf algebra you need to be careful about finite dimensionality.  Even for the trivial Hopf algebra (whose modules are vector spaces) only the subcategory of finite dimensional modules is rigid.  I think the situation for comodules is cleaner than for modules because for comodules finite dimensionality can be rephrased in terms of finite generation.  So I think you get that the category of finitely generated (presented?) comodules is rigid despite not getting that result for modules.

Answer (score 2):

The category of the finite dimensional comodules of a hopf algebra over a field, is a rigid, monoidal category. (just as the category of the finite dimensional modules).

If we take a fin dim, right comodule $X$, of the hopf algebra $H$ then its dual vector space $X^*$, equipped with the unique comodule structure satisfying $e_V(\phi_{(0)}\otimes v)\phi_{(1)}=e_V(\phi\otimes v_{(0)})S(v_{(1)})$ provides the corresponding left dual object, i.e. the right $H$-comodule $X^*$ which is the left dual of the right $H$-comodule $X$. (I am not sure however for the last part of your question: if there exists some general relationship between left and right dual objects).

In fact, more can be shown. In [On hopf algebras and rigid monoidal categories, Isr. J. of Math. v.72, p.252–256, (1990)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02764622), Ulbrich has shown that:

> An ordinary bialgebra $H$, over a field $k$, is a hopf algebra if and only if its category of finite dimensional comodules is rigid.

There, the author essentially uses the dual object to "reconstruct" an antipode for the original bialgebra.